# How to associate existing autoscaling group to elastic beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a python web application which I need to deploy on AWS. But when I try to create an environment the beanstalk wizard tries to create a new security group, launch configuration and autoscaling group. My problem is I don't have rights to create new security group and I was provided with pre configured security groups, autoscaling groups and launch configuration by someone else. The launch configuration is created by copying the launch configuration created by Beanstalk wizard if the beanstalk wizard was allowed to create the security groups and all. So it does have all the bootstrapping code. How do I create a BeanStalk environment which will use the existing Autoscaling and security groups ? I don't see any option for that on the UI Wizard. I also couldn't find if its possible to achieve by .ebextensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk uses AWS CloudFormation to manage the resources it uses. CloudFormation cannot use existing resources.

The Auto Scaling group, security groups, etc. must be created by Elastic Beanstalk.

You will need to go back to your IT team (that provided those resources) and work the permission issues out. Or don't use EB.